# Is web3j version 5.0.0 discontinued?

Tags: web3j

On [maven's release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/core) page, web3j 5.0.0 is the highest release version for web3j, which was released in May 2020.
The most recent releases of web3j are in 4.x version series. Interestingly, the [web3j releases page](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/releases) has no trace to version 5.0.0.

What happened with version 5.0.0? Is it safe to use this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.0.0 is 3 years old and probably best ignored.

https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/1976#issuecomment-1809820843 says that 5.0.0

> isn't actually the newest version, as seen when comparing the dates of
> releases [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/core). No idea why a previous version was called 5.0.0, but
> it's actually 3 years old